# MegaRAID Storage Manager: cannot set Patrol Read properties

Tags: megaraid

When I click on "Set Patrol Read Properties" **nothing happens**, e.q. no window opens in which I can set all properties regarding the Patrol Read.

The MegaRAID Storage Manager version is 16.02.00.04 running on Windows 7.

Any idea how I can fix it? The program is running as a Java applet - can this be a reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was a bug in the version 16.02.00.04. I installed the latest version 16.11.00.03 and now the window opens and I can change the settings.

Comment: You can accept your own answer